# How to resolve an unresolved symbol?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking

Greetings.

I'm having a problem dynamically linking my lib to my program.
Here's what's happening : I'm developing a modular program and testing the module system. The thing is my modules uses some class that are defined in the main binary : some abstract classes, which don't cause any issues, and a very concrete class, which just can't be resolved.

I'm using the dlopen / dlsym / dlclose set of functions.
And I compile using g++.

The thing is : if I ask dlopen to load all the symbols, then it fails telling me `"undefined symbol: _ZNK3zia3api8DataTreecvRKSsEv`
But if I launch dlopen in lazy mode, it will only happen at the first usage of the so-called class (and crash right after that).

So this is the "DataTree" class, and I want to make it available for both the main binary and the modules.
I already tried to compile it in each of the binaries : as I expected, it didn't work.
I also tried to make it entirely inline, but it's as useless as my other attempt.
I tried to compile the main binary with the option "-rdynamic". No changes.

I've been searching, asking to friends since yesterday but nobody seems to know how to solve this kind of problems.

I compile the objects of the module with the option -fPIC, like this :

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -c mysource.cpp
```

And then I use this line to make the library :

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,mylib.so.1 -o mylib.so mysource.o
```

I suppose the best solution would be to not compile the object within the library, but to make the symbol available from the main binary.
So the question is : how to do so ? (and is it what I must do ?)

Comment: demangled name is zia::api::DataTree::operator std::string const&() const

Comment: You can get (on linux) the demangled name using the `c++filt` utility. Invocation is just `c++filt _ZNK3zia3api8DataTreecvRKSsEv` and the result is what @Industrial posted. Very handy!

Comment: Good lord ! This is indeed undefined ! I didn't notice it ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Matthieu M.: c++filt says "zia::api::DataTree::operator std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&() const" but I used abi::__cxa_demangle from #include <cxxabi.h>

Comment: @Industrial: right, the `std::basic_string` bit can be a little daunting :p

Comment: So, it was an undefined cast operator? Weird :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-rdynamic` to the library module not the main program, and ensure that all your classes which have virtual methods and are inherited have a virtual destructor. Another suggestion: make a minimal example and post it here.

Comment: The class causing it doesn't have any virtual method except for its destructor. I also doble-checked : I am using -rdynamic already, and am now doing it both on the main binary and the library (juste in case). Still no changes :/ !